# Try-except bug in a while

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I ran into a particularly infamous problem: I'm creating a sort of console program on Python 3.6, but when I write a command that is not 'exit' or 'shutdown', if this command is incorrect, the console enters the loop and keeps trying to execute the incorrect command by spamming in the console the error message defined with the 'except' instruction.

I tried to delete the 'try' and 'except' statement, but in this way, if the command is incorrect, the program is interrupted and the closing command is not executed.

P.S. I forgot to write that with the 'try-except' instruction, if i press enter without writing anything, the bug leaves the same.

## Machine code - Start

```
        import os
        print("$ ", end="") #No end-line
        console_standard_input = input()
        while console_standard_input != ".shutdown":
            if (console_standard_input == "exit"):
                print("Shutting down machine...")
                sys.exit(-1)
            try:
                machine_exec_script_path_complete = "Disk\{0}".format(console_standard_input)
                os.system(machine_exec_script_path_complete)
            except:
                print("Unable to exec this function - Error")
                print("")
            print("$ ", end="")
        #Machine code - Stop
```

I haven't been able to find a solution yet.
I'm not very good at Python, so I wanted to ask the help of an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import os
print("$ ", end="") #No end-line
console_standard_input = input()
while console_standard_input != ".shutdown":
    if(console_standard_input == "exit"):
        print("Shutting down machine...")
        sys.exit(-1)
    try:
        machine_exec_script_path_complete = "Disk\{0}".format(console_standard_input)
        os.system(machine_exec_script_path_complete)
    except:
        print("Unable to exec this function - Error")
        print("")
    print("$ ", end="")
    console_standard_input = input()
```

Explanation - if you wish to keep evaluating input - you have to put `input` there explicitly. Assigning `input()` to a variable assigns only it's value (user input), not the whole operation i.e. it doesn't force it to repeat, whenever the variable is reevaluated...

Comment: I DO NOT BELIEVE IT!
I had already heard of the break but had never practiced it because I never informed myself ...

Thank you very much and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Wait, there's a problem:
if I break, the program stops;
I want the execution (in case of exception) to return to the while loop, I don't want the whole program to be interrupted ...

That is, it must be like a terminal: if it fails to execute the command, it must ask me which command to execute do you understand?